# Turning Off Auto Update on JDK installation of Java 8

Tags: java, windows, java-8

Does anyone know how to turn off the Auto Update feature of Java 8 when installed as a JDK?

We use puppet to install java 8 JDK on hundreds of TeamCity windows agents. The silent installation works fine but the default is to turn on Java Auto Update. Then sometimes the Java update process hangs waiting on someone to reply to the auto update prompt. How can we turn off auto update for JDK installations.
I've seen that this can be done with a configuration file at installation for JRE installation but I can't find anywhere on how to set that up for JDK installations.

Answer (score 0):

The only thing I can think of is to disable the auto updater that loads on startup. This applies to most versions of Windows:

```
enter code here
- Start menu
- type in my config and hit the first option
- navigate to the start up programs tab and find something along the lines of "java auto updater" and select it and press the disable button.
```

Another way of doing it is by using CCleaner: it has a built in option to disable startup programs + it is very useful for cleaning the registry and junk files.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to leave out the updater you can take a different approach: download the [server JRE](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/server-jre8-downloads-2133154.html) provided by Oracle. Despite its name it contains a JDK. The only downside for you might be that this JDK is only available as x64 because it is Oracles policy to only provide this version on servers.

Here is the content of the `.tar.gz`, which can be unpacked using 7-zip for example. You can clearly see that there is a `javac.exe` inside that archive:

[image: JavaC.exe inside Oracles x64 Server JRE]